# Docker service exits with "up", but "start" works

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openldap

My app has 5 containers. One of them is a custom built OpenLDAP container.

If I issue the command `docker-compose up`, all services start well but the openldap one exits in few seconds. No errors are shown in the slapd process running within the container. Container exit code is 137.

While the other services were running, if I start the openldap sevrice by `docker-compose start openldap`, it starts well and keeps running. Very less often I see that some other service goes down silently once I start openldap.

I keep wondering, if there's a hard limit in number of services I can launch with docker-compose?

My Host OS is windows and all my containers are CentOS 7 based.

`docker logs` shows these entries

```
59bbbd65 backend_startup_one: starting "dc=testdomain,dc=org"
59bbbd65 bdb_db_open: "dc=testdomain,dc=org"
59bbbd65 bdb_db_open: database "dc=testdomain,dc=org": dbenv_open(/var/lib/bdb-data).
59bbbd65 backend_startup_one: starting "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
59bbbd65 hdb_db_open: "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
59bbbd65 hdb_db_open: warning - no DB_CONFIG file found in directory /var/lib/ldap: (2).
Expect poor performance for suffix "dc=my-domain,dc=com".
59bbbd65 hdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": dbenv_open(/var/lib/ldap).
59bbbd65 slapd starting
59bbbd65 daemon: added 3r listener=(nil)
59bbbd65 daemon: added 6r listener=0x19adf5a490
59bbbd65 daemon: added 7r listener=0x19adf5a550
59bbbd65 daemon: added 8r listener=0x19adf5a610
59bbbd65 daemon: added 9r listener=0x19adf5a6f0
59bbbd65 daemon: added 10r listener=0x19adf5a850
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
59bbbd65 daemon: activity on:
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=6 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
59bbbd65 daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
myapp_openldap_1 exited with code 137
```

Comment: What goes `docker logs <container>` have to say?

Comment: Nothing. It shows only the logs from slapd during its startup. Edited to include logs output

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was because of less Memory allocated to Docker Engine. I had to increase it from 2GB to 4 GB in my Docker -> Advanced -> Memory

This helped:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21083#issuecomment-329374116